# Is it proper to ask to belay a request to a superior?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

The term belay is often used to cancel an order in military settings. [The definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belay) indicates it just means to cancel. However, would asking a superior (in a civilian private sector employment situation) add an improper tone to the request?

Comment: I do not think we can answer this question. Each person's situation with regard to their superiors is different. It depends entirely on how relaxed an environment you are in as to if you can tell you superior to do things.

Comment: I was actually requesting them not to do something I previously asked them to do, belaying my original request. The question was not about asking about word usage. Obviously asking my superior to do something depends on the organization and the request.

Comment: **No** - you can't grammatically *"belay a request **to** a superior"*. You can *"pass a request **[on] up to** a superior"*, for example, but OP's proposed usage of *belaying to another person* isn't valid.

Comment: Are you by any chance a rock-climbing enthusiast?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about office etiquette.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Belay* is commonly used in nautical settings (not military) to mean "stop."  Any sailor might use it in this context; it is not limited to belaying orders.

Using it in a different setting might come across as endearing, pert, obnoxious, or charming, depending on your relationship with the superior with whom you are speaking, and the manner in which you use it.

However, the word *belay* in and of itself is not rude or offensive.

Comment: You can belay, rappelling down the outside of the building with the request in hand, or you can use the stairs: both strike me as proper, but the former seems more daring.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever heard anyone use _belay_ in that fashion in the U.S. I also don't think that, if I were to do so, anybody would understand what I meant. There are other meanings to _belay_, as pointed out, and which few know; but few know any of them. I suspect its unlikeliness would make most people think they'd heard _relay_ instead, which could contribute to misunderstanding. Anything important enough to be _belayed_ should be belayed with pipes and sideboys; actual commands have to be clear and precise.

Comment: @JohnLawler I've seen a similar usage to fortunate1's in the US: when a rock/etc climbers ascent/decent was controlled by someone above working the rope instead of the climber controlling his motion directly.

Comment: @JohnLawler which usage have you not heard?

Comment: The one that means to stop.

Comment: @JohnLawler, It is very commonly used in the US Navy and Marine Corps - and even in "Star Fleet". Captain Picard often says, "Belay that", or "Belay that order".  In the Corps, we often used "Belay my last" - meaning I rescind that last command, order, or even just my last statement.  "They are in a red car."  "Belay my last, they are in a blue car."

Comment: @TracyCramer: Thank you. I'm familiar with the usage from reading, of course; but since I don't move in naval circles I don't know anybody who uses it in speech. I hadn't thought of ST, though; that may mean it's more comprehensible in general than I expected.

Answer (score 7):

In the sea services (Navy, Marines, Coast Guard), "belay" means to ignore a foregoing statement or order that a person has given. If it's an order, only the person giving the order or someone above him or her can belay an order.  One would never use the term "belay" when attempting to persuade a superior to cancel their statement or order.

Comment: To clarify, I made a request to my superior, and then I wished to rescind that request.

Answer (score 5):

There is no situation in the US Military where "belay that order" is appropriate. In a situation where one would like a sailor to disregard an order the correct statement is "as you were." While colloquially "belay that order" makes grammatical/logical sense, it is simply not correct.

However, in civilian life, it is not technically inappropriate. It may sound pedantic, like saying indubitably instead of yes, but it is not improper.

With that being said, who knows what your boss may find offensive, so I would stay away from the phrase.

Comment: The first sentence is factually incorrect. It was a commonly used phrase in the US Marine Corps both times I served (88-92 and again 05-06).

Comment: I too would like to add that "belay that order" is correct in the US Navy, but in such situations where it was appropriate, it would also be common to shorten it to belay that, since the word 'order' would be understood.

Comment: Even if it were true that the *US* military doesn't use the term, there are rather a lot of other military groups in the world. OP didn't mention a particular country.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S. Marine Corps and U.S. Navy, and all other branches of naval service, the word "Belay" is used as a manner to disregard and to rescind, e.g.:

- > "Corporal, I need you and five Marines to drop what you are doing, and get over to the barracks and police call the beer-garden. I want all of those cigarette butts gone and stray beer cans gone. If it doesn't grow, it goes."
  >   "-- Uh, actually, belay that. Staff Sergeant has second squad on it already. You guys sweep the cat-walks."
- > "Hernandez, you see that flashing over that dune? Looks like muzzle flashes, let me glass it and see what it is, I can't tell what it is. Light it up with the 240."
  >   "Belay that! Cease fire, cease fire!"

Answer (score 1):

Mskfisher used the term correctly. Usage and branch of service the term is most utilized by i.e.

> Lieutenant, 'Light 'em up!!'
>   Sgt Mgr, 'Belay that, they're friendlies'

Comment: I can't work out what you mean by "Usage and branch of service the term is most utilized by". Could you maybe expand on that, ideally in complete sentences rather than note-form? Thanks.