# How did 'belay' semantically shift to mean `forget I said that'?

Tags: etymology

[word choice - Is it proper to ask to belay a request to a superior? - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60866/is-it-proper-to-ask-to-belay-a-request-to-a-superior/118161)

> In the sea services (Navy, Marines, Coast Guard), "belay" means to ignore a foregoing statement or order that a person has given. If it's an order, only the person giving the order or someone above him or her can belay an order. One would never use the term "belay" when attempting to persuade a superior to cancel their statement or order.

I can't spot this meaning  on the [*OED*](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/17325?rskey=brTbmL&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid), but chanced upon an explanation on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-in-the-military-ever-actually-been-told-to-Belay-that-order/answer/Eric-Husher). Can someone please expound it and fill in the gaps?

> It is a very specific expression to the NAVY, and meaningless to anyone else. To ‘belay’ means to STOP, and comes from wrapping a running line around a cleat. Such a line is called ‘belayed’ once it has been so secured. This term has been tranferred over to other purposes, such as to stop an action, or impending action (just like stopping a line from running). In the Army, the command is ‘as you were,’ or if a wrong order is given while marching, the countermand is ‘continue to march.’

[belay (v.) | Origin and meaning of belay by Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/belay#etymonline_v_8267)

> "to secure or fasten," from Old English belecgan, which, among other senses ("cover, invest, surround; afflict; accuse"), meant "to lay a thing about" (with other objects),
> from [be-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/be-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) + lecgan "to lay" (from PIE root [*legh-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*legh-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to lie down, lay").
> The only surviving sense is the nautical one of "coil a running rope round a cleat or pin to secure it" (also transferred to mountain-climbing), first attested 1540s; but this is possibly from Dutch cognate beleggen.

[Belay | Definition of Belay by Oxford Dictionary on Lexico.com also meaning of Belay](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/belay)

> 2. nautical slang [usually in imperative] Stop; enough!
>
> *‘“Belay that, mister. Man your post.”’*

Comment: The first sentence of that Quora explanation is certainly wrong, the expression is *not* meaningless to people outside the navy. I would have thought most fluent English speakers familiar with it.

Comment: Anyone who's watched Star Trek knows the "nautical slang" meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks "No! Belay that phaser order! Arm photon torpedoes!"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an error.

Comment: Not that the Navy used shanties but I understand that it was common for a shantyman to break off the song and out call "Belay" when the task was complete. Obviously the song would stop at that point but in many cases it would be necessary to belay the line or all the hauling would be pointless. Maybe the term "Belay" meaning "stop what you're doing" came from this circumstance.

Comment: It has been used this way since before 1700 in English, and apparently also in French.  There's no particular reason to think it is directly related to the maritime term, except that the maritime belay may have helped to preserve the other meanings that have largely disappeared outside maritime parlance. For instance, we used to belay a road to stop wagons from being able to use it (the 1600's version of roadside IEDs).

Comment: a) cp. German *beilegen*, chiefly legalese "Streit beilegen" (rest a case, seize an argument), not *belegen*, *belegt* (q.v.). English lost or never had this distinction, if En. *be-* is anyway interpreted as *by*. b) An odd idiom with *obey* vs *belong* is seen in Ger. *gehören* and more languages (see ling.SE; no conclusion); cp. *belangen* (q.v.), or *aufhören!* "stop", *aufpassen* "to stop, pay attention" versus "to listen *up*" (off?), at least for analogy. c) I'm not sure if Ger. *leise* "quiet" compares *lesen* "read, lect.", *lehren*, *lernen* "learn", much less sure for *belay*.

Comment: d) cp. *leiern, anleiern, beleiern* for something close to "wind". tl;dr: I suppose one way or another your preponderance only shows off a coincidental resemblance. The quoted quora answer is a non-sequitur anyway. Since this is a rather negative opinion, I won't commit to an inconclusive answer without strong evidence.